# Identify this battery power connector for a portable water pump

Tags: connector, identification

Total layman when it comes to electrical issues.

I'm looking for the industry-standard name of the connector imaged below:

[image: Battery charger]

This charger is meant to charge the battery below (provided here for clarity):

[image: Battery to be charged]

I would like to identify this power connector, in order to buy another higher mAh battery that can link to the device this battery is supposed to connect to, for longer operating times. I'm thinking of a USB battery such as an Anker Astro power bank / external battery.

So, to summarise:

1. What is the **white output** connector shown in these images?
2. Would it be possible to use such batteries instead of the one shown below? Can I find a USB-to-this-connector convertor? I'd presume that this is a yes, given they are both lithium-based batteries, but I'd like a confirmation before investing...

Comment: You have an 11.1V volt battery. Your pump won't run off of 5 volts (as output from a USB power pack).

Comment: You may be able to get something together, but you need to make sure the charging circuit is designed for the battery in question, especially when it comes to lithium batteries. They can explode or catch fire if not charged correctly. Likewise, the batteries can be ruined if allowed to discharge too much. Sometimes this is handled by the battery, sometimes this is handled by the electronics it powers.

Comment: @DoxyLover So I can't use some sort of converter to step up the voltage from the USB, or is this dangerous? Alternatively, do you know of any good alternative solutions?

Comment: @Jarrod Christman If I've understood you correctly, I'm going to charge my USB battery using its own charger, but I will be powering the pump with the USB battery via USB.

Comment: Yes, a boost regulator would work, but I don't think you'll find anything off-the-shelf. Also, keep in mind that you need to be comparing power (watt-hours) not amperage (amp-hours). Your current battery is 31,080 watt-hours (2800 * 11.1). A 10,000 mAH USB pack is actually 36,000 watt-hours since the battery pack inside is 3.6 volts, as @Passerby noted below.

Comment: Ah, so the difference in power capacity is actually not that great? That makes things look a bit less bleak. Thanks @DoxyLover!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe pictures are horrible, and you can't tell what the connectors look like. I believe it has a clip on the long side instead of the short? It's impossible to tell. You can look at Molex brand power connectors [0.93 pitch here](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=standard_093&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=power_connectors) and [0.62 pitch here](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=standard_062&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=power_connectors) to see if you find it.

That said, you're better off if you get some standard ones and cut and solder them on to the charger and your battery, as trying to find a battery with the same connector will be hard.

As for the USB battery pack idea, no. USB battery packs are typically 3.6V LiPo batteries.

Update: based on a slightly better picture, it seems to be a Tamiya power connecter, typically found in Radio Controlled model vehicles and planes.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's got only two holes? Here's another image - looks a bit clearer here. http://www.veskimo.com/prodimages/veskimo-quick-change-power-pack-2-400.jpg

Comment: @A.Tawfik in that case it looks a bit like a Tamiya power connector.

Comment: @A.Tawfik updated

Answer (score 0):

The connecter looks like a Molex Mini Fit Junior type. [Molex Mini Fit jr series](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=minifit_jr&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction)